# Scroll to item with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios13, uicollectionviewlayout

I've implemented `UICollectionView` using new `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. Also I use `Core Data` + `NSFetchedResultsController`. I want to scroll to item when it is inserted. I use `orthogonalScrollingBehavior` for section and I can't scroll to item using methods

`func selectItem(at indexPath: IndexPath?, animated: Bool, scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition)`

or

`func scrollToItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, at scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition, animated: Bool)`.

How to scroll to new item?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing the UICollectionView.ScrollPosition to .centeredHorizontally. In my case the first section had an orthogonalScrollingBehavior horizontally.

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: self.indexToScroll, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```